# react-phone-input-2 with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I want validate phone number with react-hook-form. Phone valid return true but form is not valid. Here is my controller, how can I fix this?

Here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-water-f570c

````
<Controller
        render={() => {
          return (
            <PhoneInput
              country={phoneRegion}
              value=""
              defaultValue={false}
              countryCodeEditable={false}
              placeholder=""
              onChange={() => {
                console.log(phoneValid, isValid);
              }}
              isValid={(inputNumber, country, countries) => {
                const region = country.iso2;
                const number = phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput(
                  inputNumber,
                  region
                );
                setPhoneRegion(country.iso2);
                phoneUtil.isValidNumber(number)
                  ? setPhoneValid(true)
                  : setPhoneValid(false);
                return countries.some((country) => {
                  return (
                    startsWith(inputNumber, country.dialCode) ||
                    startsWith(country.dialCode, inputNumber)
                  );
                });
              }}
            />
          );
        }}
        register={register}
        name="phoneNumber"
        control={control}
        rules={{ required: true }}
        specialLabel="Phone Number"
      />```
````

Comment: Still an issue or don't you need any more help? Better ask before I help, not that you have already solved it....

Comment: Hi @okh did you fixed it or you need any help?